# Creating a folder with file in Android's internal storage

Tags: android, storage, internal

i'm trying to create a folder with a .csv file inside in android internal storage, but the folder doesn't appear in the regular file explorers.

The code is the following.

```
private String FOLDER_NAME = "app_folder";

File folder = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + FOLDER_NAME);
if( !folder.exists() ) 
    folder.mkdir();
```

Answer (score 4):

> but the folder doesn't appear in the regular file explorers.

That is because [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) cannot be viewed by any sort of file explorer, except on emulators or rooted devices.

File explorers — on-device and desktop — usually examine [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).